# Proving the given function is continuous

Tags: calculus, functions

If $f:I \rightarrow R$ is a function satisfying
$$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq z|x-y|,$$
for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $z \in \mathbb{R}^+$, then show that $f$ is continuous on $I$.

It can be re-written as:
$$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|\leq z.$$
But, does this imply something? I'm not able to begin with this proof. Please help through some hints on how to solve this. I don't expect answers as I would like to try it out myself first. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity!!

Comment: Try the definition of continuity: that, for every $a$, then $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$$

Comment: ohh..got it.... :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\;y\in I:=$ domain of definition, and let $\;\epsilon>0\;$ be arbitrary. Choose now $\;\delta:=\frac\epsilon z\;$, so:

$$|x-y|<\delta=\frac\epsilon z\implies |f(x)-f(y)|=z|x-y|<z\frac\epsilon z=\epsilon$$

and we're done